# python regular expressions function not working

Tags: python, regex, function

I am learning python so this may be a simple question for alot of you and i hope to get some help in understanding what is going wrong.

I am trying to create a function that searches a text for phone numbers.

```
    import re

def findPhoneNumber(a):
    b = re.compile(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')
    c = b.search(a)
    return c.group()

findPhoneNumber('123')
```

I am getting this error: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

so for my understandings, the c variable is not getting any values associated and thus is returning this error.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: your regex won't match `123`, try with `findPhoneNumber('123-213-1234')`

Comment: Thanks it did work..

Comment: and, of course, do not indent `import re`

Comment: Replace `return c.group()` with `return c.group() if c else ""`

Comment: Thanks, I see where my problem was. I did not return any value if the function did not work so I had the error displayed.
Thank you all for the pretty fast help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example "123" does not match any phone number, you need "123-456-7890".

So in your example `c==None`. You have to test that `c` is an actual match object with `if(c)` before trying to access `c.group()`

Answer (score 2):

If your regex doesn't match anything `c` would be `None` giving you the next exception:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

You just need to handle that exception

```
def findPhoneNumber(a):
    try:
        return re.search(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', a).group()
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

Also it has little sense to compile the regex inside the function to use it just one time